# How do i remove this background color from the other span after click another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i made a span to have a background color when i clicked on its link but when i clicked another span i want the background color of the other one to be removed and and appear in the current one. please how do i do that.

**CSS**

```
                list-style: none;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 7px 0px 7px 23px;
            }

            ul li a {
                color: #676a74;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            ul li a span {
                float: left;
                width: 11px;
                height: 11px;
                margin-left: -13px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                top: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #d1d3d7;
                position: relative;
                transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            }

            ul li a span.active {
                background: green;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
            <li>
                <a href=""><span class="list"></span>Electronics</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""><span class="list"></span>Clothes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""><span class="list"></span>Home & Office</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().find(".list").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: First, remove active from all span then add active to your clicked one

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(".list").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of a tag remove active class from all list class.now add active class to span which is children of a tag which clicked.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
 $(".list").removeClass("active");
 $(this).children('.list').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
ul{
   list-style:outside none none;
}
ul li a {
                color: #676a74;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
ul li a span {
                float: left;
                width: 11px;
                height: 11px;
                margin-left: -13px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                top: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #d1d3d7;
                position: relative;
                transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            }

            ul li a span.active {
                background: green;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="list"></span>Electronics</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="list"></span>Clothes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="list"></span>Home & Office</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

for add active class on span click

```
    $('.list').click(function(){
       $(".list").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass('active');
    })
```